# Deadlocks during logon to ASP app caused by dropping/creating SQL Server views

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services

I have been chasing this issue for a day now and am stumped, so thought I would put it out to you folks for some inspiration.  I'm a bit of a novice when it comes to deadlocks and SQL Server lock modes, I rarely need to delve into this.

### The short story:

When a user logs into our application, we want to update a SQL Server view based on the fact that they now have a "session", so that when they subsequently run a SQL Server Reporting Services report based on a report model, it includes security settings for their session.

The regular deadlock I've noticed is occuring between the process that DROPs and reCREATEs the view (which I call the AuthRuleCache), and a Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services 2008 (SSRS) report that tries to select from the view.

The if I read the SQL Profiler deadlock event properly, the AuthRuleCache has a Sch-M lock, and the report has an IS lock.

The AuthRuleCache code is C# in a DotNet assembly, it's executed when users log into our Classic ASP app.

Obviously I want to avoid the deadlock because it's preventing logins - I don't mind how I achieve this as long as I don't need to compromise any other functionality.  I've got full control over the AuthRuleCache and the database, but I would say that we're "light" on enterprise DBA expertise.

Here is an example deadlock event from SQL Profiler:

```
<deadlock-list>
 <deadlock victim="process4785288">
  <process-list>
   <process id="process4785288" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="OBJECT: 7:617365564:0 " waittime="13040" ownerId="3133391" transactionname="SELECT" lasttranstarted="2013-01-07T15:16:24.680" XDES="0x8005bd10" lockMode="IS" schedulerid="8" kpid="20580" status="suspended" spid="83" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="0" lastbatchstarted="2013-01-07T15:15:55.780" lastbatchcompleted="2013-01-07T15:15:55.780" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="MYMACHINE" hostpid="1176" loginname="MYMACHINE\MyUser" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="3133391" currentdb="7" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="2" stmtstart="34" sqlhandle="0x02000000bd919913e43fd778cd5913aabd70d423cb30904a">
SELECT
    CAST(1 AS BIT) [c0_is_agg],
    1 [agg_row_count],
    COALESCE([dbo_actions2].[ActionOverdue30days], 0) [ActionOverdue30days],
    COALESCE([dbo_actions3].[ActionOverdueTotal], 0) [ActionOverdueTotal],
    COALESCE([dbo_actions4].[ActionOverdue90daysPLUS], 0) [ActionOverdue90daysPLUS],
    COALESCE([dbo_actions5].[ActionOverdue60days], 0) [ActionOverdue60days],
    COALESCE([dbo_actions6].[ActionOverdue90days], 0) [ActionOverdue90days],
    COALESCE([dbo_actions7].[ActionPlanned30days], 0) [ActionPlanned30days],
    COALESCE([dbo_actions8].[ActionPlanned60days], 0) [ActionPlanned60days],
    COALESCE([dbo_actions9].[ActionPlanned90days], 0) [ActionPlanned90days],
    COALESCE([dbo_actions10].[ActionPlanned90daysPLUS], 0) [ActionPlanned90daysPLUS],
    COALESCE([dbo_actions11].[ActionPlannedTotal], 0) [ActionPlannedTotal],
    CASE WHEN [dbo_actions12].[CountOfFilter] > 0 THEN 'Overdue0-30days' WHEN [dbo_actions13].[CountOfFilter] > 0 THEN 'Overdue90daysPlus' WHEN [dbo_actions5].[Count     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
  SET DATEFIRST 7
  SELECT
    CAST(1 AS BIT) [c0_is_agg],
    1 [agg_row_count],
    COALESCE([dbo_actions2].[ActionOverdue30days], 0) [ActionOverdue30days],
    COALESCE([dbo_actions3].[ActionOverdueTotal], 0) [ActionOverdueTotal],
    COALESCE([dbo_actions4].[ActionOverdue90daysPLUS], 0) [ActionOverdue90daysPLUS],
    COALESCE([dbo_actions5].[ActionOverdue60days], 0) [ActionOverdue60days],
    COALESCE([dbo_actions6].[ActionOverdue90days], 0) [ActionOverdue90days],
    COALESCE([dbo_actions7].[ActionPlanned30days], 0) [ActionPlanned30days],
    COALESCE([dbo_actions8].[ActionPlanned60days], 0) [ActionPlanned60days],
    COALESCE([dbo_actions9].[ActionPlanned90days], 0) [ActionPlanned90days],
    COALESCE([dbo_actions10].[ActionPlanned90daysPLUS], 0) [ActionPlanned90daysPLUS],
    COALESCE([dbo_actions11].[ActionPlannedTotal], 0) [ActionPlannedTotal],
    CASE WHEN [dbo_actions12].[CountOfFilter] > 0 THEN 'Overdue0-30days' WHEN [dbo_actions13].[CountOfFilter] > 0 THEN 'Overdue90daysPlus' WHEN [db    </inputbuf>
   </process>
   <process id="process476ae08" taskpriority="0" logused="16056" waitresource="OBJECT: 7:1854941980:0 " waittime="4539" ownerId="3132267" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2013-01-07T15:16:18.373" XDES="0x9a7f3970" lockMode="Sch-M" schedulerid="7" kpid="1940" status="suspended" spid="63" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2013-01-07T15:16:33.183" lastbatchcompleted="2013-01-07T15:16:33.183" clientapp=".Net SqlClient Data Provider" hostname="MYMACHINE" hostpid="14788" loginname="MYMACHINE\MyUser" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="3132267" currentdb="7" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="3" stmtstart="202" stmtend="278" sqlhandle="0x02000000cf24d22c6cc84dbf398267db80eb194e79f91543">
  DROP VIEW [sec].[actions_authorized]     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>

  IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM sys.VIEWS WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[sec].[actions_authorized]'))
  DROP VIEW [sec].[actions_authorized]
      </inputbuf>
   </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
   <objectlock lockPartition="0" objid="617365564" subresource="FULL" dbid="7" objectname="617365564" id="lock932d2f00" mode="Sch-M" associatedObjectId="617365564">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process476ae08" mode="Sch-M"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process4785288" mode="IS" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </objectlock>
   <objectlock lockPartition="0" objid="1854941980" subresource="FULL" dbid="7" objectname="1854941980" id="locke6f0b580" mode="IS" associatedObjectId="1854941980">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process4785288" mode="IS"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process476ae08" mode="Sch-M" requestType="convert"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </objectlock>
  </resource-list>
 </deadlock>
</deadlock-list>
```

### The LONG story:

I've decided to do this as a Q&A.

Q: Why do you have to make frequent schema changes just to enforce security on reports?

A: Well, I only arrived that this approach because our SSRS reporting mechanism is totally based on report models, and our application supports row-level security by applying rules.  The rules themselves are defined in the database as little SQL fragments.  These fragments are re-assembled at run-time and applied based on a) who the user is, b) what they are trying to do, and c) what they are trying to do it to.  So, each user may have a unique view of the data based on the rules that apply to them.  We have users authoring and saving their own reports, so I wanted this security enforced at the model to prevent them from stumbling upon data they should not have access to.

The challenge we faced with report models is that they are based on a data source view (DSV) that can only be made up of static sources, e.g. tables, named-queries, views.  You cannot inject some C# code into the DSV to get it to dynamically respond to the particular user running the report.  You do get the UserID at the model (SMDL) so you can use this for filtering.  Our solution is to get the DSV to expose a view with ALL of the data for ALL of the currently logged in users' unique rulesets (namely, the AuthRuleCache), then the SMDL will filter this back to the unique ruleset of the requesting user.  Hey-presto, you've got dynamic row-level, rule-based security in an SSRS report model!

The rules change infrequently, so it's OK for these to behave the same way for the duration of a user's session.  Because we have tens of thousnds of users, but only a few hundred or so may log in during a 24 hour period, I decided to refresh the AuthRuleCache any time a user logs in and expire it after 24 hours so it contains only security info for users with current sessions.

Q: What form does the AuthRuleCache take?

A: It's a view UNIONing a buch of other views.  Each user has their own view e.g. widgets_authorized_123 where widgets is the table containing data being secured, and 123 is the user id.  Then, there's a master view (e.g. widgets_authorized) that UNIONs together all the user views

Q: That sounds hideously inefficient, are you a moron?

A: Possibly - however thanks to the awesomeness of the SQL Query Processor, it all seems to run nice and fast for live user reports.  I experimented with using a cache table to actually hold record-ids for use with the application security and found this led to bloated-tables and delays refreshing and reading from the cache.

Q: Okay, you may still be a moron, but let's explore another option.  Can you rebuild the AuthRuleCache asynchronously instead of having the user wait at logon?

A: Well, the first thing the user does after logon is hit a dashboard containing reports based on the model - so we need the security rules up and running immediately after logon.

Q: Have you explored different locking modes and isolation levels?

A: Sort of - I tried enabling altering the database read_committed_snapshot ON but that seemed to make no difference.  In retrospect, I think the fact that I'm trying to do a DROP/CREATE VIEW and requiring a Sch-M lock means that Read Committed Snapshot Isolation (RCSI) wouldn't help because it's about handling concurrency of DML statements, and I'm doing DDL.

Q: Have you explored whole-database database snapshots or mirroring for reporting purposes?

A: I wouldn't rule this out, but I was hoping for more of an application-centric solution rather than making infrastructural changes.  This would be a jump in resources utilization and maintenance overhead which I'd need to escalate to other people.

Q: Is there anything else we should know?

A: Yes, the AuthRuleCache refresh process is wrapped in a transaction because I wanted to make sire that nobody gets to see an incomplete/invalid cache, e.g. widget_authorized view referring to widget_authorized_123 when widget_authorized_123 has been dropped because the user's session has expired.  I tested without the transaction, and the deadlocks stopped, but I started getting blocked process reports from SQL Profiler instead.  I saw ~15 second delays at login, and sometimes timeouts - so put the transaction back in.

Q: How often is it happening?

A: The AuthRuleCache is switched off in the production environment at the moment so it's not affecting users.  My local testing of 100 sequential logons shows that maybe 10% deadlock or fail.  I suspect it is worse for users that have a long-running report model based report on their dashboard.

Q: How about report snapshots?

A: Maybe a possibility - not sure how well this works with parametized reports.  My concern is that we do have some users who will be alarmed if they insert a record but don't see it on the dashboard until half an hour later.   Also, I can't always guarantee everyone will use report snapshots correctly all the time, so don't want to leave the door open for deadlocks to sneak back in at a later date.

Q: Can I see the full T-SQL of the AuthRuleCache refresh transaction?

A: Here are the statements issued inside one transaction captured from SQL Profiler for one user logging on:

Look for expired sessions - we'd delete the associated view if found

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME LIKE 'sec.actions_authorized_%'
  AND RIGHT(TABLE_NAME, NULLIF(CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE(TABLE_NAME)), 0) - 1) NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT CAST(empid AS NVARCHAR(20))
    FROM session
    )
```

Drop any pre-existing view for user 'myuser', id 298

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM sys.VIEWS
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[sec].[actions_authorized_298]')
    )
  DROP VIEW [sec].[actions_authorized_298]
```

Create a view for user id 298

```
CREATE VIEW [sec].[actions_authorized_298]
AS
SELECT actid
  ,'myuser' AS username
FROM actions
WHERE actid IN (
    SELECT actid
    FROM actions
    WHERE (
        --A bunch of custom where statements generated from security rules in the system prior to this transaction starting
    )
```

Get a list of ALL user specific views for the actions entity

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME LIKE 'sec.actions_authorized_%'
```

Drop the existing master actions view

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM sys.VIEWS
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[sec].[actions_authorized]')
    )
  DROP VIEW [sec].[actions_authorized]
```

Create a new master actions view and we're done

```
CREATE VIEW [sec].[actions_authorized]
AS
SELECT actid
  ,username
FROM sec.actions_authorized_182    
UNION
SELECT actid
  ,username
FROM sec.actions_authorized_298
UNION
-- Repeat for a bunch of other per-user custom views, generated from the prior select
-- ...
```

Comment: Feels like reading a novel.

Comment: re-creating views like this seems like a poor design.  Could you use a Table valued function as part of the 'master' view that filters the user's security?

Comment: Thanks Mitch.  I experimented with TVFs and also .NET CLR procedures but could not find a way to get decent performance.  The DSV does not support parameters, so DSV tables/views/queries need to supply ALL the data which is then filtered down for the user when the report is executed.  Re-creating views was the only way I found to support custom, user-specific security logic but also let the SQL Query Processor do all its optimization at runtime.  Can you suggest an efficient way for a TVF to apply dynamic (i.e. not known at design-time) security rules on a model entity?

Comment: I think this is fixable. Can you post the deadlock graph (as XML) obtained using SQL Profiler? I'm unclear what exactly deadlocks with what. My understanding is that recreating a view might block but I do not see a great potential for deadlocks.

Comment: Poor design. Bad enough. Well, have fun.

Comment: Looks like you are doing multiple things in that `drop view` transaction. Can you post all of them? One hack that you can always do is to `SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY HIGH` in one of the transactions to at least get one to fail deterministically. You can retry it, then.

Comment: Thank usr.  I've added the T-SQL of the transaction above.  I am conscious that it's hitting a lot of system tables and is a pretty chunky process to happen in a transaction for every login.  I considered building the new master view under a temporary name then doing an sp_rename on it at the last minute to try to minimize its impact - however I read that sp_rename is discouraged for views.

Comment: Try this: Remove the `IF` test above `DROP VIEW [sec].[actions_authorized]`. Also, uncomment "Look for expired sessions" as it seems non-essential and can be split into a 2nd transaction. Play around with transaction boundaries, for example put everything regarding the master view into a separate transaction.; This is really just trying to make this work by coincidence by shuffling things around. I lack the time to dig into this more thoroughly.

Comment: Tinkering with the transaction boundaries hasn't fixed it yet.  Switching the transaction isolation level to SERIALIZABLE appears to prevent the deadlocks, but I'm still getting blocked process events in Profiler as you anticipated usr.  Makes sense, I guess there's no way I can drop & recreate a view without waiting for a report to stop using the view.  I might investigate SNAPSHOT isolation a bit further, maybe see if I can avoid DROP VIEW or ALTER VIEW and just always create new views.

Comment: A very long post that manages to dance around the most important issues: 1) What do the user's "rules" look like? (be specific and give examples) 2) Why couldn't they be encoded as data in Tables rather than as code in Views?

Comment: Hi Barry the rules are not the issue.  They are dynamic based on a number of parameters, and they are defined in tables.  This works fine throughout the bulk of the app.  The ONLY place I need to push these rules into per-user views is the SSRS report models, which do not support any form of query that takes dynamic parameters - I have experimented with TVFs using CROSS APPLY but that resulted in hideous runtime performance because it prevents the query optimizer from doing anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all who offered suggestions.  I've settled on a solution that I think will work for us.  It may be a while before I get the final code together, but I've done some tests and it's looking positive - I wanted to close this question off with my planned approach.

Firstly, the deadlocks are a totally appropriate consequence of what I was trying to do from the outset.  As I understand, recreating a view requires a schema modification lock - and any process in the middle of reading from that view requires a schema stability lock.  Dependent on timing, these competing locks resulted in a deadlock in about 10% of logon attempts during busy periods.

When I changed the code to do a SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE before running the view drop/recreate, the deadlocks went away because it is much more restrictive about what can happen concurrently, sacrificing response speed for stability.

Unfortunately, instead of deadlocking, I was seeing blocked process reports where processes were waiting upwards of 10 seconds to obtain the necessary locks.  Still not really solving my problem.

I had a rethink about my "weird solution" of using a big UNIONed view to combine multiple views.  Let me be clear that I didn't arrive at this approach by choice, I am simply trying to work around a limitation in SSRS Report Models whereby you can't implement parameters in the tables/named queries underlying the model.

I found in MS documentation that Partitioned Views can use a similar structure when merging together rows from multiple tables into a single view, example here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190019(v=sql.105).aspx

So I'm not alone in using views in this way.  I need this UNIONed view, but dropping and recreating views is going to be a performance problem.  So, I did some testing using Service Broker and found I could queue up the view drop/recreate operation, allowing users to log in rapidly without waiting around for the for the DDL to complete.  I'm going to follow @usr's suggestions and get the transaction as lean as possible, moving stuff not critical to completing a logon (such as expiring old sessions) out of the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use your example with widgets, I assume there is a table which says which widgets are authorized for each user (if you have user groups it's just a bit more complex)

As you are using User_ID, I assume you have another tables with the user logins.

Users (User_ID, Login)
Widgets (Widget_ID, ...)
widgets_authorized (User_ID, Widget_ID)

Rename the table Widgets to AllWidgets

Create the view Widgets:

```sql
CREATE VIEW widgets
AS
SELECT AW.*
FROM AllWidgets AW
INNER JOIN widgets_authorized WA ON WA.Widget_ID = AW.Widget_ID
INNER JOIN Users U ON WA.User_ID = U.User_ID
WHERE U.Login = SYSTEM_USER
```

You can keep the previous model linked to the view Widgets instead of the previous table Widgets, they return the same columns, the data is filtered according to the connected user.

If you have performance problems try this one, I had a similar problem:

```
CREATE VIEW widgets
AS
SELECT AW.*
FROM AllWidgets AW
INNER JOIN widgets_authorized WA ON WA.Widget_ID = AW.Widget_ID
WHERE WA.User_ID IN (SELECT U.User_ID FROM Users U WHERE U.Login = SYSTEM_USER)
```

Comment: Hi @atesio - thanks for this suggestion but we're not quite there yet.  This is a SaaS website with thousands of users (employees).  We have written a custom authentication extension for SSRS, and we use a single Windows identity when authenticating with SQL Server.  So, SYSTEM_USER will return MYDOMAIN\MySharedAccount for all access to the model irrespective of the particular user logged into the website.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion closer to your weird solution.

Instead of several views with a single schema, create views with an unique name and several schemas: sec_182.actions_authorized

Run your query with "FROM actions_authorized", don't explicit the schema, the sql engine will use the view which belong to the connected user schema.

The schema and its views may be created with a background process or at user logon (CREATE TRIGGER ... ON ALL SERVER ... AFTER LOGON ...)

Comment: Ingenious suggestion but similar difficulty as your other one.  The earliest that the view knows the identity of the person running the report is when the SSRS execution engine builds its big query and appends a WHERE statement including the userid.